# How does matlab's latex interpreter handle unicode?

Tags: matlab, unicode, matlab-figure

I'm wondering how MATLABs latex interpreter for plot text deals with unicode characters?  It is weirdly inconsistent. Which, y'know, invalidates the whole ENTIRE point of unicode.

TOY CODE

```
%*** Setup some text for a plot title
Title_Txt{1} = [char(8734) ,' SNR~~~' , char(10) , '(-)'];
Title_Txt{2} = ['50 SNR~~~' , char(10) , '(-)'];


%*** Plots!
x= 1:1:10
y= rand(size(x))

figure(1)
subplot(211)
plot(x,y)
title(Title_Txt{1} , 'interpreter' , 'latex')

subplot(212)
plot(x,y)
title(Title_Txt{2} , 'interpreter' , 'latex')
```

[image: Toy plot]

Toy code demonstrates that the latex interpreter handles char(10) --- a new line. But it breaks from char(8734) --- the infinity symbol.

Obviously I can work around this by feeding in a latex symbol that matlab knows (another source of frustration but that's for a different discussion), but I am curious about

- what MATLAB is doing under the hood here?
- is there is a fix for getting unicode into latex?

Comment: Also matlab doesn't list the Unicode format they use in the documentation.  I guess that "Valid codes range from 0 to 65535" means "char() interprets based on unicode UTF-16"?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the (unsatisfying) answer here is that the Latex interpreter portion of Matlab does whatever the included version of Latex does, and Latex in general doesn't support Unicode. (For Latex solutions, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex. Of course this doesn't help Matlab users.)

As to why Latex doesn't support Unicode. I'll note that the first copyright date on my Latex users' guide is 1985, and the latest release is version 2e, from 1994. Unicode was not really mainstream until the '90's.

(This is a poor answer, but became too long for a comment.)

Comment: Interesting info nonetheless!   I hadn't really considered LaTeX might be fundamentally unicode non-compliant, despite the fact I use LaTeX every day.

Comment: This is more than likely the best answer that could be given since MATLAB probably simply calls pdfTex, which isn't Unicode friendly like the LuaTex or XeTeX engines, without options to play nice with Unicode. This is one reason I publish raw LaTeX using `matlab2tikz` and choose the engine I want.  @Mark_Anderson